# with XMLDIFF, how to compare only the fields that my xml elements have in common?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

**introduction:**

I have query using a pipeline function. I won't change the names of the returned columns but I will add other columns.

I want to compare the result of the old query with the new query (syntaxal always the same (select * from mypipelinefunction) , but I have changed the pipeline function )

I have used "select *" instead of "select the name of the columns" because there is a lot names.

**code:**

the code example is simplified to focus on the problem addressed in the title. (no pipeline function. Only two "identic" queries are tested. The second query has one more column that the first.

```
SELECT 
    XMLDIFF (
        XMLTYPE.createXML (
            DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml ('select 1 one, 2 two from dual')),
    XMLTYPE.createXML (
            DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml ('select 1 one from dual'))) 
from dual.
```

I want that XMLDIFF to say that there is no difference because the only columns that I care about are the colums that are in common.

In short I would like to have this result

> <xd:xdiff xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/xdiff.xsd [http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/xdiff.xsd"](http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/xdiff.xsd%22) xmlns:xd="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/xdiff.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

</xd:xdiff>

instead of this result

> <xd:xdiff xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/xdiff.xsd [http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/xdiff.xsd"](http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/xdiff.xsd%22) xmlns:xd="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/xdiff.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><xd:delete-node xd:node-type="element" xd:xpath="/ROWSET[1]/ROW[1]/TWO[1]"/></xd:xdiff>

Is this possible to force XMLdiff to compare only the columns that are in commun?

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=01b88b40e6882f2b7e146ca688f63198)

Another way to fix this problem would be to have a shortcut in TOAD that transform `select * from t` in `select first_column, ......last_column from t`. And it should work even if t is a pipeline function

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about certain columns then wrap your query in a outer-query to only output the columns you care about:

```sql
SELECT XMLDIFF (
         XMLTYPE.createXML (
           DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml (
             'SELECT one FROM (select 1 one, 2 two from dual)'
           )
         ),
         XMLTYPE.createXML (
           DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml (
             'SELECT one FROM (select 1 one from dual)'
           )
         )
       ) AS diff
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | DIFF |
> | --- |
> | <xd:xdiff xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/xdiff.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/xdiff.xsd" xmlns:xd="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/xdiff.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><?oracle-xmldiff operations-in-docorder="true" output-model="snapshot" diff-algorithm="global"?></xd:xdiff> |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=710161753f5ec73b087382321b77f3d8)*

Comment: @MTO thanks it  works but I have a lot of column. I would rather avoid writing all this colums. And I would like to automate this example with a lot function. I would like if it is possible to avoid changing the query and only give a indication to XMLDIFF.

Comment: @MTO I've seen in https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions257.htm#SQLRF20025 that XMLDIFF can take flags but I don't find what are these flags

Comment: @Pierre-olivierGendraud Look in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/XMLDIFF.html#GUID-B7746C15-27FD-4CAF-87EA-49C0DFA1E935) and then follow the link to the [Oracle XML Developer's Kit Programmer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf&id=ADXDK2510) then you can scroll down to the flags for the C API and the SQL function takes the same flags. (TL;DR they won't help you do what you want.)